# How to receive form-data submitted through post request on front-end javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm going to integrate a payment-gateway service into my project. Based on the documentation provided by this payment-gateway service, I required to submit some values to its pages.

Below codes are the way on how I perform submission of form-data to it.

```html
<form method="POST" [formGroup]="formService.ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event)" name="ePayment"
        action="https://www.mobile88.com/ePayment/entry.asp">
    <input type="hidden" name="MerchantCode" [value]="merchantSetting.merchantCode">
    <input type="hidden" name="SignatureType" [value]="merchantSetting.signatureType" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Signature" [value]="generatedSignature | async" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ResponseURL" [value]="merchantSetting.responseUrl" />
    <input type="hidden" name="BackendURL" [value]="merchantSetting.backendUrl" />

    <ion-label>{{ 'paymentPage.referenceNumber' | translate }}</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" name="RefNo" [value]="referenceNumber" readonly="true"></ion-input>

    <ion-label>{{ 'paymentPage.currency' | translate }}</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" name="Currency" value="MYR" readonly="true"></ion-input>

    <ion-label>{{ 'paymentPage.productDescription' | translate }}</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" name="ProdDesc" readonly="true" [value]="packageSubscriber | async"></ion-input>

    <ion-label>{{ 'paymentPage.amount' | translate }}</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" name="Amount" readonly="true" [value]="amount"></ion-input>

    <ion-label>{{ 'paymentPage.username' | translate }}</ion-label>
    <ion-input formControlName="username" type="text" name="UserName">

    <ion-label>{{ 'paymentPage.userEmail' | translate }}</ion-label>
    <ion-input formControlName="userEmail" type="text" name="UserEmail"></ion-input>
    <ion-label>{{ 'paymentPage.userContact' | translate }}</ion-label>
    <ion-input formControlName="userContact" type="text" name="UserContact"></ion-input>
    <ion-button type="submit" class="submit-button" value="Proceed with Payment" name="Submit">
          {{ 'paymentPage.proceedWithPayment' | translate }}
    </ion-button>
</form>
```

```
  async onSubmit(e) {
    if (this.formService.ngForm.valid) {
        e.target.submit();
    }
  }
```

After form submission, the user will be redirected to the web-page of the payment gateway and make the payment. Once the payment was made, the payment-gateway will be redirected back to responseUrl (which is our angular front-end) we provided in form-submission with some payment information attached via POST method. In this case, how can I able to retrieve these value with the javascript?

I have tried to do some googling and it turns out that most of the people will directly use the php code such as below to receive value in html but in our project stack, the frontend and backend are totally separated. Is there any way to do this?

```php
  $_POST["name"]

  $_POST["email"]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Posting forms is for sending the data to the server, forms that are posted respond with a new web page. This is not how things are usually done in Angular. In Angular you usually use either template forms or reactive forms to bind forms to objects and then send the data back to the server with the Angular HttpClient.

The question you are asking is basically how do I do forms in Angular which is really out of scope for a StackOverflow answer. You need to go a read up on Angular forms and once you understand that then you need to understand Angular service on how to pass data between pages.

Comment: Hi Adrian, my flow is as below (my web app submit value to third party web page -> third party submit values back to my web app). My intention is to get the post submit data sent from third party so it is not the problem that can solve with using angular service to share the data between pages.

Comment: Save your order back to your server and reload it when the payment gateway redirects back to your site.

Answer (score -1):

Store the info you are sending via Post locally using session storage. That way you could hold on the info as long as you don't close the tab/window.

Comment: Don't use session storage for Angular, use an Angular service.